# How to generate a vector with unique values?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization-list

I have this example to generate unique objects into a vector :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int v=0;

struct A
{
    A() : refValue( v++)
    { std::cout<<"constructor refValue="<<refValue<<std::endl; }
    A( const A &r ) : refValue(r.refValue)
    { std::cout<<"copy constructor refValue="<<refValue<<std::endl; }
    A& operator=( const A &r )
    {
        refValue = r.refValue;
        std::cout<<"operator= refValue="<<refValue<<std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    ~A() { std::cout<<"destructor refValue="<<refValue<<std::endl; }

    int refValue;
};

A GenerateUnique()
{
    A unique;
    return unique;
}
struct B
{
    B( const int n) : v()
    {
        std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( v ), n, &GenerateUnique );
    }
    std::vector< A > v;
};

int main()
{
    B b(3);
}
```

If I change my main into this :

```
struct B
{
    B( const int n) : v(n)
    {
    }
    std::vector< A > v;
};
```

then one object of type A will be copied into all vector elements.

Is there a way to create a vector with all unique objects (like in the 1st example)?

To make it more clear : I have a class containing a vector. This vector must contain all unique objects (not a copy of one object). And I would like to initialize it in the initialization list (not in the body of the constructor).

Comment: I know I could use `boost::assign::list_of`, but for that but you have to know the number at compile time. I need a solution which works works at run time.

Comment: As written, this really doesn't make sense. Perhaps you're confusing C++ and Java? Because in C++, std::vector<A> contains distinct objects, not references to them. Therefore, a vector<A> with N members contains N distinct objects, not N pointers to a single object.

Comment: @MSalters Right, but it contains N copies of the same object. Would you suggest an edit to make it clearer?

Comment: I'm not sure. It currently looks like `A() != A()` which is rather counter-intuitive. You could move the state into `GenerateUnique()`. However, in that case your `std::generate_n()` solution is in fact idiomatic.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the constructor body? IMO it exists exactly for what you're doing: non-trivial initialization. If you really wanted, turn your first `main` into a function that returns `as`, then you can just copy-initialize, but then you might as well just do it in the constructor body.

Comment: And of course the usual: *why*? This is awfully unorthodox, maybe there's a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: @GMan The vector contains objects of a type that shouldn't be copied (copy constructor is doing a shallow copy - a bug in design or implementation, not sure). Anyway, I am not allowed to change that class. I was wondering if there is a way to generate this vector in the initialization list. Bo Persson's answers seems to clear the doubts.

Answer (score 3):

It gets copied because that constructor's signature is as follows:

```
​explicit vector( size_type count,
             const T& value = T(),
             const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

It is evident that you just pass a default-constructed object to this constructor and it copies it.

If you want to initialize in the initializer list, you are limited to constructors of some objects, obviously. I guess, you wouldn't like to create a wrapper class just to initialize the vector in initializer list, soo we are limited to vector's constructors. The only one that seems reasonable is

```
template <class InputIterator>

vector( InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So you can create an iterator to return the needed number of default-constructed objects.

I suggest just constructing in the constructor body though.

Comment: Maybe the last definition could be used with [boost function input iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_input_iterator.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Your first attempt is the one that works.

In the current standard C++03 this line

```
std::vector< A > as( n );
```

is explicitly defined to create one `A` object and copy that `n` times.

I belive that in C++0x this is changed to create `n` default constructed `A`s (a small difference). Then you might perhaps be able to do something in `A`s constructor to make each instance unique.

Right now you cannot.

Comment: on c++0x, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector mentions this (3rd constructor), it says that it makes copies anyway (a bit controversial as why then create a separate constructor). Is than incorrect? Do you have a link to c++0x standard's statement about this?

Comment: @unkulunkulu from n3290, 23.3.6.2 vector constructors, copy, and assignment [vector.cons]: 3. Effects: Constructs a vector with n value-initialized elements.

Comment: Seems like an error in the description here : en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: Nope, that's not an error. The third constructor is used only when explicitly asked (no implicit conversions apply), whereas the second can take advantage of the implicit conversions, thus the distinction

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, you could use `make_function_input_iterator` from boost as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/iterator/function_input_iterator.hpp>

// A && GenerateUnique the same ...
struct B
{
    B( const int n) : v(boost::make_function_input_iterator(&GenerateUnique, 1), boost::make_function_input_iterator(&GenerateUnique, n))
    {
    }
    std::vector< A > v;
};

int main()
{
    B b(3);
}
```

Note however that when I tested the code I saw a bit more copy constructing/operator= going on than in your first solution. Next to that, also an additional object (refvalue 3) was created (for the last "stop" iterator). I do not know if this additional behaviour is feasible, but it does the trick of initializing the vector in your initializer list if you really want it.

Comment: As said by Bo Persson, the current version of c++ (c++03) provides no other ways of doing that. Your version seems to be the only way.